# <g:if> and <g:set>misunderstanding in grails

Tags: html, grails, button, if-statement

I have a gsp template.
And I have varialble. If this variable is `true`, then create an additional button, if `false` - do nothing.

What is wrong with my code?

```
<g:set var="removeButton">{{ removeButtonPossibility }}</g:set> // variable from model, is true or false
<g:if test="${removeButton == true}">
   <button id="removeDocument">Delete</button>
</g:if>
```

It doesn't work. But just using: `${removeButton}` normally prints `true` or `false`.

Comment: If gsp is anything like jsp (as it appears to be), the entire `g:set` statement is superfluous.  In theory it should work simply as `<g:if test="${removeButtonPossibility}">...</g:if>`.

Comment: ok, but my problem is that the if statement is not working... it is adding <button> in evety case

Comment: Can you post the code from the action in the controller?

Comment: Try `<g:set var="removeButton" value="${removeButtonPossibility}"/>`

Answer (score 2):

What about doing the easy thing? :)

```
<g:set var="removeButton" value="${removeButtonPossibility}" />
<g:if test="${removeButton}">
    <button id="removeDocument">Delete</button>
</g:if>
```

Or, even better:

```
<g:if test="${removeButtonPossibility}">
    <button id="removeDocument">Delete</button>
</g:if>
```